# Does connecting a Windows 7 computer to a Windows domain automatically disable the Windows startup sound?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, windows-domain, system-sounds

When using any Windows 7 computer that's connected to a Windows domain, I've noticed that the default startup sound appears to be disabled. Is this automatically disabled as part of the domain joining process? It's worth noting that the checkbox to play the startup sound is missing from the "Sounds" tab of the Sound applet within the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

That is not an issue or problem with Windows 7 machines on or off a domain.

> Is this automatically disabled as part of the domain joining process?

This is not part of a regular domain restriction, so now you need to look at your own policies and see whether they can be changed.

Windows 10 does not have a startup sound and companies may have eliminated Windows 7 startup sounds as a possible source of irritation to employees.